# Segmentation fault using mongodb c++ client driver

Tags: c++, linux, mongodb

I am getting a segmentation fault in a program that uses the C++ mongodb client driver.
Attempting to isolate the problem I found this: there is some heap object of class X.
When commenting out all the mongo code the program runs fine.
But if I add a member variable of type BSONObjBuilder to X (just declare without using it),
then after about 200K iterations where X objects are allocated and deallocated the fault occurs.
Gdb bt shows it's in the destructor of X, which is actually {}, so it only disposes of the BSONObjBuilder.
It looks like the free memory list is getting corrupted.
Having a BSONObjBuilder as a local variable on the stack works though, over millions of iterations.

I have found this related question https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/Ngxh4IOcSPA
which suggests there is a linkage problem. So I rebuilt the mongo C++ driver as indicated, but the
problem persists. There is also this question on the matter
[MongoDB C++ Segmentation Fault](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14635506/mongodb-c-segmentation-fault)
with similar rebuild recommendations but for older mongo versions.
Not being an expert, I would appreciate some help in finding out exactly what library mismatch may cause this and how to reinstall/rebuild/fix it properly.

Some details:

- I have ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
- dpkg -S /usr/include/boost/version.hpp shows libboost1.54-dev
- mongod 2.6 running, although after commenting out I'm not even connecting to it.
- downloaded the legacy mongo C++ driver git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver.git
- built scons driver and scons install, which uses g++, compiled fine, generated libmongoclient.a
- my code in Eclipse also uses g++, everything compiled with -pthread (there are multiple threads)
- a single additional include path to mongo-cxx-driver/build/include for the mongo driver stuff
- libraries linked as follows (in order): mongoclient, pthread, boost_thread, boost_system, boost_regex
- tried with pthread the last library, no help
- calling mongo::client::initialize first thing in main, status returned ok
- I have some BSONObj members in X, they work fine until I also add the BSONObjBuilder member
- Tried calling done() or abandon() on the BSONObjBuilder in the destructor, also no help.

Comment: `Attempting to isolate the problem I found this: there is some heap object of class X. When commenting out all the mongo code the program runs fine.`  At the very least, please post this code that you say works "fine".  Working fine doesn't mean there is no issue with the code.

Comment: I realize that working much longer without memory corruption is no guarantee. However, from the posts I mentioned, I was assuming the most likely cause is library mismatch and I hoped someone would see something obvious here. The code is kind of large to post, I will need to work on it to show something relevant. Bottom line for now is: without the BSONObjBuilder declared, my unit test runs 100++ million transactions; with it it crashes after 100-200K. Other than that, X is a passive object containing a few other strings.

Comment: Here's the issue with what you're saying -- If you take a look at the SO post you linked to, you see that the poster created a very small main() program, and called a couple of library functions.  No other code was needed to duplicate the error.  Thus a conclusion can be made that the library is faulty in some way.  What you have done is describe a much larger program, and no way can anyone know whether it is a library issue or not.  You may be trying to uproot the whole application, when the real problem lies in something you're doing wrong.

Comment: Yes, I will need to work on it to isolate the error in a much simpler environment that I can present.

Comment: Have you tried running your application under valgrind or address sanitizer?

Comment: Sorry for not updating this earlier. After re-installing linux I could no longer reproduce the problem. It seems there may have been one of the issues with installing boost mentioned by the other answers; I did have a failed installation at some point. However I can't tell what. Anyway, there does not seem to be any issue with the mongo c++ driver, so I need to give them credit.